# Grails or Spring constant time comparison function?

Tags: spring, grails

I'm looking for a method similar to the [Rails secure_compare method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SecurityUtils.html) or Node's `crypto.timingSafeEqual` for Grails 3 or Spring.

Is this something that either framework supports?  Or should I simply use native Java Message.isEqual?

Answer (score 0):

Here the guys do not recommend using MessageDigest.isEqual(...): https://codahale.com/a-lesson-in-timing-attacks/

And here might be the solution you are looking for: https://github.com/cossacklabs/themis/blob/master/src/wrappers/themis/java/com/cossacklabs/themis/SecureCompare.java

Comment: It looks like MessageDigest.isEqual is constant time for Java versions > 6, ill go with that